# How to get the difference between now and a different date (in minutes) using ksh (or another shell script)?

Tags: shell, date, ksh

Giving two variables with the followind values:

```
date1 = Mon Feb 27 16:21:34 WET 2012
date2 = Mon Feb 27 16:29:34 WET 2012
```

How can I make the difference (in minutes) between them using ksh?

**I'm using Solaris 10.**

---

**I made what you said and this was the error:**

```
$ function d { echo $((($(date -d"$2" +%s)-$(date -d"$1" +%s))/60)); }
$ d "Mon Feb 27 16:21:34 WET 2012" "Mon Feb 27 16:29:34 WET 2012"
date: illegal option -- d
date: illegal option -- M
date: illegal option -- o
date: illegal option -- n
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- F
date: illegal option -- e
date: illegal option -- b
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 7
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option -- 6
date: illegal option -- :
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 9
date: illegal option -- :
date: illegal option -- 3
date: illegal option -- 4
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- W
date: illegal option -- E
date: illegal option -- T
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 0
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option -- 2
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
date: illegal option -- d
date: illegal option -- M
date: illegal option -- o
date: illegal option -- n
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- F
date: illegal option -- e
date: illegal option -- b
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 7
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option -- 6
date: illegal option -- :
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option -- :
date: illegal option -- 3
date: illegal option -- 4
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- W
date: illegal option -- E
date: illegal option -- T
date: illegal option --
date: illegal option -- 2
date: illegal option -- 0
date: illegal option -- 1
date: illegal option -- 2
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
0
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, here's a C program that might work. it's (lightly) tested on solaris.

it uses the POSIX standard [strptime(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html) function to parse a given string and prints the result in epoch seconds.

in theory invocation should be

```
$ ./strptime "Mon Feb 27 16:21:34 WET 2012" "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
```

but i haven't been able to get it to recognize the "WET" timezone, so you may need to just put that in as a literal:

```
$ ./strptime "Mon Feb 27 16:21:34 WET 2012" "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S WET %Y"
1330377694
```

here's the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARGS 3
#define USAGE printf("Usage: %s string format\n",argv[0]);
#define EARGS { printf("%s: %s arguments (%d)\n",argv[0],argc<ARGS?"Insufficient":"Too many",argc-1); USAGE; exit(2); }

#define err(_s,_p,_f) {fprintf(stderr,"%s: %s: %s\n",(_p),(_f),strerror(errno));exit(_s);}

int main(int argc,char**argv){
        struct tm tm;
        time_t t;

        if(argc!=ARGS)EARGS;

        strptime(argv[1],argv[2],&tm);
        if(-1==(t=mktime(&tm)))err(1,argv[0],"mktime");
        if(0>printf("%lld\n",(long long)t))err(1,argv[0],"printf");
        return 0;
}
```

compile with something along the lines of

```
$ CFLAGS='-W -Wall -Wshadow -std=gnu99' make strptime
```

(probably requires gcc, no idea if sun cc will work here)

Answer (score 1):

using a `date` which supports `-d`,

```
$ function d { echo $((($(date -d "$2" +%s)-$(date -d "$1" +%s))/60)); }
$ d "Mon Feb 27 16:21:34 WET 2012" "Mon Feb 27 16:29:34 WET 2012"
8
```

Comment: Check the answer, I've updated with the error that our code gave

Comment: can you install gnu date? do you have perl or python available? alternatively, where are these datetimes coming from? can you modify the code that's generating them to output something more machine friendly, like the `+%s` format for `date`?

Comment: I cannot install gnu date but I have perl, if needed :)

Comment: well, here's a C program that might work. it's (lightly) tested on solaris.

Comment: Needs a space after the `-d` option to date in each of the two places that's used.  I edited it in already.

Comment: @mc0e It works fine w/o the space on my box. Are you using GNU `date`, or some other `date` that also implements that `-d`?

Comment: @AaronDavies I'm using gnu date as provided on Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop, and it looks OK without the space.  Not sure now where I had the issue without, but it would have been a Debian or Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have GNU date. You might have Tcl installed:

```
$ printf 'puts [expr {abs([clock scan "%s"]-[clock scan "%s"])/60}]' "$date1" "$date2" | tclsh
8
```

Comment: No, I don't have Tcl installed!