# Find Difference in timestamps in seconds

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, solaris, ksh

I have 2 files with timestamps  in the format of `MMDDYYYY-HHMMSS`.
For eg. `04192012-000623` and `04192012-000854`.

I need to be able to find the difference between the 2 in seconds.

Special cases to check for

- the dates straddling midnight. For eg: `04172012-115500` & `04182012-000200`.
- it shouldn't matter which file comes in first, etc.

I am running ksh with no access to the `date -d` flag. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to shell script this? (It is going to be a part of a larger shell script so no other languages please)

This is intended to be run on both solaris and linux ksh. Thanks in advance.

Comment: python available? for pure ksh implementation you can find some inspiration [here](http://www.unix.com/302130352-post7.html)

Comment: Sorry I am looking for a shell script solution.

Comment: Why can't you use any other language at all?

Comment: Mostly for educational purpose - I would like to see how this can be done in a shell script. Also, to be able to integrate this into larger existing shell scripts.

Comment: What ksh versions are you targetting ? Gnu/Linux distributions might have pdksh or ksh93. Solaris 10 and older has ksh88 and dtksh. Solaris 11 has ksh93.

Comment: It is Solaris 5.9. How do I find out which ksh it has?

Comment: I answered to that question (ksh88 and dtksh, an old ksh93). What ksh are you using on linux ?

Comment: there are many questions here about this problem or closely related. search with `[bash] [ksh] date time`. (most bash solutions should work without change in newer ksh ). `echo ${.sh.version}` to see what you have. I nothing is set for that value, then you're using old ksh88 (which is still relatively powerful and capable for this task). Good luck.

Comment: if this is just for fun, good luck :). if it's for actual practical purposes, see my `strptime` wrapper at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908915/how-to-get-the-difference-between-now-and-a-different-date-in-minutes-using-ks/10044607#10044607, it should be easily adaptable to this.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter (from my provided link above):

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

echo enter first time stamp
read TIME1
echo enter second time stamp
read TIME2
H1=${TIME1%:+([0-9])}
M1=${TIME1#+([0-9]):}
H2=${TIME2%:+([0-9])}
M2=${TIME2#+([0-9]):}
H1=${H1#0}
M1=${M1#0}
H2=${H2#0}
M2=${M2#0}
((MAM1=H1*60+M1))
((MAM2=H2*60+M2))
((MAM1>MAM2)) && ((MAM2=MAM2+1440))
((diff=MAM2-MAM1))
echo diff = $diff

exit 0
$ ./timestamp
enter first time stamp
17:30
enter second time stamp
18:05
diff = 35
$ ./timestamp
enter first time stamp
23:59
enter second time stamp
00:01
diff = 2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is just for fun, good luck :). if it's for actual practical purposes, see my `strptime` wrapper at [How to get the difference between now and a different date (in minutes) using ksh (or another shell script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908915/how-to-get-the-difference-between-now-and-a-different-date-in-minutes-using-ks/10044607#10044607), it should be easily adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses gnu-date and bashisms, since I don't know ksh.

```
d1=04192012-000623
dd1="${d1:4:4}/${d1:0:2}/${d1:2:2} ${d1:9:2}:${d1:11:2}:${d1:13:2}"
d1=04192012-000854
dd2="${d1:4:4}/${d1:0:2}/${d1:2:2} ${d1:9:2}:${d1:11:2}:${d1:13:2}"
echo $(($(date -d "$dd1" +%s) - $(date -d "$dd2" +%s)))
```

Maybe ${var:from:len} is not available in ksh to cut parts from strings, then you have to replace it with something else, maybe sed.

Answer (score 0):

stat -c followed by one of the following

```
   %X     time of last access, seconds since Epoch

   %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch

   %Z     time of last status change, seconds since Epoch
```